# Python Selenium -- Searching for a link but finding cards

Tags: python, selenium

Using Python + Selenium to create a web crawler/scraper to notify me when new homework is posted. Managed to log into the main website, but you need to click a link to select your course.

After searching through the HTML manually, I found this information about the link I usually click (The blue box is the link).
[image: html info on link]
However, no button that seems clickable. So I searched the page for the link I knew it should redirect me to, and I found this:
[image: card information]
It looks like a card, which is a new data structure/object for me. How can I use an automated web crawler to click this link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ui.WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".title.ellipsis")))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".title.ellipsis").click()
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Updated the picture to reflect the link's html. Still getting NoSuchElementException.

Comment: @Ra31513, how is going?